# javascript importing modules with threejs and three-globe using only the browser and CDNs

Tags: javascript, three.js, es6-modules

I am trying to use threejs and three-globe together, using only the CDN distributions from unpkg, but I am getting tripped up by modules. I am hoping to avoid using a build tool but perhaps that's not doable.

I started with the very basic example right from the top of the [three.js README](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js). I have an index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
        <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Threejs basic app</title>
                <style>
                        body { margin: 0; }
                </style>

<script type="importmap">
        {
                "imports": {
                        "three": "https://unpkg.com/three/build/three.module.js"
                }
        }
</script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>

        </body>
</html>
```

and a main.js, copied from the jsfiddle:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

const width = window.innerWidth, height = window.innerHeight;

// init

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, width / height, 0.01, 10 );
camera.position.z = 1;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 );
const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( mesh );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
renderer.setSize( width, height );
renderer.setAnimationLoop( animation );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

// animation

function animation( time ) {

        mesh.rotation.x = time / 2000;
        mesh.rotation.y = time / 1000;

        renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

And all works fine.

Where I get tripped up is when I want to include [three-globe](https://github.com/vasturiano/three-globe/). If I try to import it like so, as the first line of the three-globe README suggests:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import ThreeGlobe from 'https://unpkg.com/three-globe@2.30.0/dist/three-globe.js';


const width = window.innerWidth, height = window.innerHeight;

// rest of the code is the same
```

This fails, with the javascript console telling me

`Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://unpkg.com/three-globe@2.30.0/dist/three-globe.js' does not provide an export named 'default' (at main.js:2:8)`

No problem, it's not a module, let me try what I think is the module version:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import ThreeGlobe from 'https://unpkg.com/three-globe@2.30.0/dist/three-globe.mjs';


const width = window.innerWidth, height = window.innerHeight;

// init
//rest of the code is the same
```

This fails, because I apparently to help it find dependencies:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "kapsule". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

So I tried with a namespace import:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import * as ThreeGlobe from 'https://unpkg.com/three-globe@2.30.0/dist/three-globe.js';

const width = window.innerWidth, height = window.innerHeight;

// init
// the rest of the code is the same
```

But now it blows up trying to mess with three.js:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'BufferGeometry')
    at three-geojson-geometry.mjs:235:19
    at three-globe.js:5:98
    at three-globe.js:6:3
```

Looking at this code in three-geojson-geometry, it's rooting around and looking for window.THREE - is it not there yet?

I can make this work by ditching the import of threejs and three-globe and just using them as script tags and not modules: the new index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
        <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Threejs basic app</title>
                <style>
                        body { margin: 0; }
                </style>

<script type="importmap">
        {
                "imports": {
                        "three": "https://unpkg.com/three/build/three.module.js"
                }
        }
</script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/three"></script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/three-globe"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

and the an updated main.js

```
//import * as THREE from 'three';
//import * as ThreeGlobe from 'https://unpkg.com/three-globe@2.30.0/dist/three-globe.js';

const width = window.innerWidth, height = window.innerHeight;

// init

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, width / height, 0.01, 10 );
camera.position.z = 1;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
//rest of the code is the same
```

And that works. But now when I want to import something in main.js, I get warnings about pulling in multiple versions of three.js

an updated index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
        <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Threejs basic app</title>
                <style>
                        body { margin: 0; }
                </style>

<script type="importmap">
        {
                "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.160.1/build/three.module.js",
"three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.160.1/examples/jsm/"
                }
        }
</script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/three"></script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/three-globe"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

and an updated main.js

```
//import * as THREE from 'three';
//import * as ThreeGlobe from 'https://unpkg.com/three-globe@2.30.0/dist/three-globe.js';

import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

const width = window.innerWidth, height = window.innerHeight;

// init
// all of the rest of the code is the same
```

That works, but now it's upset that there are multiple three.js instances:

```
WARNING: Multiple instances of Three.js being imported.
(anonymous) @ three.module.js:53034
```

Following along in the network tab, `https://unpkg.com/three` 302s to `https://unpkg.com/three@0.160.1` which 302s to `https://unpkg.com/three@0.160.1/build/three.js`. The glTF module also looks like it's creating a load for `https://unpkg.com/three@0.160.1/build/three.module.js` which presumably is the 2nd copy of Three.js

So trying to head that off at the beginning, and loading it index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
        <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Threejs basic app</title>
                <style>
                        body { margin: 0; }
                </style>

<script type="importmap">
        {
                "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.160.1/build/three.module.js",
"three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.160.1/examples/jsm/"
                }
        }
</script>
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.160.1/build/three.module.js"></script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/three-globe"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

I'm now stuck with two errors in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'BufferGeometry')
    at three-globe:2:58460
    at three-globe:2:227
    at three-globe:2:238
(anonymous) @ three-globe:2
(anonymous) @ three-globe:2
(anonymous) @ three-globe:2

Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined
    at main.js:10:16
```

So I guess I'm just kinda stuck. Is there really no way to just do an `import ThreeGlobe` from main.js? I think my trouble is that ThreeGlobe is looking to hook onto the global THREE object, but I don't understand when that is actually created if I only import it in main.js. This is kind of a longshot, but is there some `await` magic I have to do with these loads to make sure that any sideeffects of the module loads have happened?

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I was able to reproduce the `WARNING: Multiple instances of Three.js being imported.` issue. My example uses the CDN https://esm.sh and inserts the example script from the `three` README inline because stackoverflow snippets don't support es modules.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "three": "https://esm.sh/three@0.160.1",
          "three-globe": "https://esm.sh/three-globe@2.30.0"
        }
      }
    </script>
    <title>three.js CDN</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module">
      import { PerspectiveCamera, Scene, BoxGeometry, MeshNormalMaterial, Mesh, WebGLRenderer } from 'three'
      import ThreeGlobe from 'three-globe'

      // console.log(ThreeGlobe)

      const width = window.innerWidth, height = window.innerHeight;

      // init

      const camera = new PerspectiveCamera( 70, width / height, 0.01, 10 );
      camera.position.z = 1;

      const scene = new Scene();

      const geometry = new BoxGeometry( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 );
      const material = new MeshNormalMaterial();

      const mesh = new Mesh( geometry, material );
      scene.add( mesh );

      const renderer = new WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
      renderer.setSize( width, height );
      renderer.setAnimationLoop( animation );
      document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

      // animation

      function animation( time ) {

        mesh.rotation.x = time / 2000;
        mesh.rotation.y = time / 1000;

        renderer.render( scene, camera );

      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I noticed from my browser's network panel, that `three-globe` was initiating the additional request for `three`, but at a different version (v0.158.0) than the one listed in the `importmap`. Basically, this mismatch in version between `three@v0.160.1` and `three@v0.158.0` caused the duplicate instances.

A potential solution is to explicitly request `three@v0.158.0` in your `importmap`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "three": "https://esm.sh/three@0.158.0",
          "three-globe": "https://esm.sh/three-globe@2.30.0"
        }
      }
    </script>
    <title>three.js CDN</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module">
      import { PerspectiveCamera, Scene, BoxGeometry, MeshNormalMaterial, Mesh, WebGLRenderer } from 'three'
      import ThreeGlobe from 'three-globe'

      // console.log(ThreeGlobe)

      const width = window.innerWidth, height = window.innerHeight;

      // init

      const camera = new PerspectiveCamera( 70, width / height, 0.01, 10 );
      camera.position.z = 1;

      const scene = new Scene();

      const geometry = new BoxGeometry( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 );
      const material = new MeshNormalMaterial();

      const mesh = new Mesh( geometry, material );
      scene.add( mesh );

      const renderer = new WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
      renderer.setSize( width, height );
      renderer.setAnimationLoop( animation );
      document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

      // animation

      function animation( time ) {

        mesh.rotation.x = time / 2000;
        mesh.rotation.y = time / 1000;

        renderer.render( scene, camera );

      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I still haven't tracked down why `three-globe` is depending on that specific version of `three`. I see that `three` is listed as a [`peerDependency`](https://github.com/vasturiano/three-globe/blob/master/package.json#L67), but haven't looked at the build or deployment details.

Comment: Good job, I was playing with that compatibility a little bit, but I could't figure out this...